# Generate inputs based on another input's value

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need to generate "n" number of inputs based on the input "players" value.
If I type "5" inside my input, I need to have 5 inputs showing up in my div "playerName".

I've already tried with "useState" hook, but I can't make it work, can you please help me ?

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import React, {useState} from 'react'; 


function GameSetup() {

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Game Setup</h1>
      <label for="players">Nombre de joueurs  </label>
      <input type="text" id="players" name="players" />
      <div class="playerName"></div>
      <div>
        <Link to="/game">
          <button>Start partie</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default GameSetup;
```

EDIT : I tried WebExp0528's answer, and it works well. But now when the input "players" is < 0 it throws me an "indalid array length" error. I spent some time trying to figuring out why it didnt work, and I think it's the "parseInt". When I remove it and try to go < 0 in my "players" input, it goes "-1"... What I need is to block it and don't go < 0 or > 5, but I don't know where to put that function in my code

EDIT : I solved that problem like this => ***players > 0 &&*** and by ***setting a min & max value for the input***

```
<div className="playerNameInput">
          
            {players > 0 && Array.from(Array(players).keys()).fill().map((value, index) => {

                return (
                <div>
                  <label name={index}>{"Nom du joueur : " + (index +1)} &nbsp;</label>
                  <input key={index} name={index} id={"playerName_" + (index +1)}/>
                </div>
                )
              })}
      
        </div>
```

Comment: There is no `useState` in your code? You only import it but there is no logic associated with it. Hint: store number of players in a state, and then use a for loop to generate the necessary number of input fields.

Comment: It looks like you're using some syntax that is compatible with HTML but not with React (use `className` instead of `class` for react tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
export default function App() {
  const [players, setPlayers] = useState(0);
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Game Setup</h1>
      <label for="players">Nombre de joueurs </label>
      <input
        type="number"
        id="players"
        name="players"
        value={players}
        onChange={(e) => setPlayers(parseInt(e.target.value))}
      />
      <div class="playerName">
        {Array.from(Array(players).keys())
          .fill()
          .map((value, index) => {
            return <input key={index} />;
          })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. To a beginner, all that `Array` stuff probably won't make any sense. Please consider editing your answer with some explanation about what is going on there and why this works.

Comment: Thank you, it works but when the array is <0 (when I delete my input players value) it throws me an error => invalid array length

Comment: I edited my question, it works fine now. Thanks to all of you !